# Does Apache OFBiz delegator API support fetching list of records from database by limit or offset

Tags: sql, database, api, ofbiz

Let's say we have to fetch only 5 records from a table but my where clause is matching 25k records in the database. So is there a way in `ofbiz` framework to just select 5 records rather than getting a list from the database and then taking just 5 from the list?

If the limit is not possible (since `ofbiz` API is database agnostic) what are my other alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look into this [entity engine cookbook](http://www.opensourcestrategies.com/ofbiz/ofbiz_entity_cookbook.txt)

Essentially for getting limited set of rows from database you would do:

```
// first get a list iterator
productsELI = delegator.findListIteratorByCondition("Product", 
  new EntityExpr("productId", EntityOperator.NOT_EQUAL, null), 
                  UtilMisc.toList("productId"), null);

// then get a partial list by count TO RETURN first 5 records
productsELI.getPartialList(0, 5);

// and finally just close the iterator
productsELI.close();
```

Also if you prefer to send **direct SQL to your database** then just do like this:

```
// gets the helper (localmysql, localpostgres, etc.) for your entity group org.ofbiz
String helperName = delegator.getGroupHelperName("org.ofbiz");
SQLProcessor sqlproc = new SQLProcessor(helperName);
sqlproc.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM PARTY LMIT 0, 5");
ResultSet rs1 = sqlproc.executeQuery();

// and then get your data from ResultSet like regular JDBC
```

Comment: How can you take String type parameter in SQLProcessor constructor ? There are no String Type parameter in SQLProcessor constructor.

Comment: [There is an API to set string value](https://ci.apache.org/projects/ofbiz/site/javadocs/org/ofbiz/entity/jdbc/SQLProcessor.html#setValue-java.lang.String-)