# Present a sql query in service engine Apache OFBiz

Tags: ofbiz

I would like to present a sql query in service engine ofbiz as follows:

**select * from A where A.a in (select B.a from B where B.b = '2');**

please help me. thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Always use the Entity-Engine if possible (try with view-entity, EntityListIterator ...)
If you really can't avoid it then SQLProcessor is the way to go. This has been answered at [Does Apache OFBiz delegator API support fetching list of records from database by limit or offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410461/does-ofbiz-delegator-api-support-fetching-list-of-records-from-database-by-limit)

Comment: Hi @ChristianGeisert, Is there any way to use `EXCEPT` similar to use in sql?